# how to see all data and fields in an object

Tags: c++, eos

I have this function:

```
void blocks_table::add(chain::signed_block_ptr block)
    {
        const auto block_id_str = block->id().str();
        const auto my_block = block;
        const std::string asset_id = "CRYPTO.EOS";
    
        using std::cout;
        using std::endl;
    
        cout << my_block << endl;
        cout << block_id_str << endl;
    
    }
```

And Output is:

```
0x7f9b900015e0 

000001bfc2cb2a343911f6e036c8dc3eed9461061e64dce396dd2d73fc404dff
```

How can i see all existing data (fields) in `my_block`, for correct parsing

Comment: `cout << *my_block` since it is a pointer, but that requires that `chain::signed_block` has a `operator<<` defined for that class

Comment: although it does not look like that class does https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/block.hpp#L89-L104 I do not know enough about that library to know what utilities they provide, but you may have to parse through the members and output them yourself

Comment: C++ doesn't have a "print this struct" thing built in, this has to be done manually by overloading `operator<<`.

Comment: If you dereference that pointer, C++ has no idea how to print your object using `operator <<`.  There is no "pretty print" function that C++ defaults to, unlike some other computer languages you may have been using.  You have to write an overload of `operator <<`, and there are tons of links and articles on how to properly do this for a custom class.